# How to restrict user to enter only numbers and enter key in textarea using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am very new to Javascript.

I have a requirement to allow `only digits and enter key as input in a textarea box`. I would also like to allow users to `paste ONLY digits into the textarea`.

After searching through the questions on StackOverflow, I  found the following:

```
function validate(key)
{
//getting key code of pressed key
var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
var phn = document.getElementById('textarea');
//comparing pressed keycodes
if (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)
{
return false;
}

<div>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50"  onkeypress="return validate(event)" />
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem completely. I want to allow users to press `enter`. How can I change the above code to allow "enter" presses as well as integer paste events?

Comment: if (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57 || keycode==13 )

Comment: @zan wrong way around. `return keycode === 13 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)`

Comment: Why not only do validation?

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu the accepted answer details how to allow only certain key presses (including some OP might not have thought of) under the **jQuery** section of the answer (though it's not jQuery specific).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty easy modification. Just add an "is equal to" statement to your code. Also, since you also want to handle paste events, you'll need an event listener and function for "onPaste."

**Method 1: Use "onPaste" Events**

```
function validatepaste(e) {
    var pastedata = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    if (isNaN(pastedata)) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
}

function validate(e) {
    //getting key code of pressed key
    var keycode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var phn = document.getElementById('textarea');
    //comparing pressed keycodes
    if ((keycode < 48 || keycode > 57) && keycode !== 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8r0vL7ty/25/)

And here's some info on the ["onPaste"](http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpaste.asp) event.

**Method 2: Use "onKeyUp" instead of "onPaste" and "onKeyPress"**

This method is less elegant, but it works if your environment doesn't support "onPaste"

```
function validate(e) {
    var invalidcharacters = /[^0-9]/gi
    var phn = document.getElementById('textarea');
    if (invalidcharacters.test(phn.value)) {
        newstring = phn.value.replace(invalidcharacters, "");
        phn.value = newstring
    }
}

<div>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="50" onKeyUp="validate(event)"></textarea>
</div>
```

And a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsfj24fp/15/)

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari I added a second method in case you don't want to support "onPaste." Please do accept if this post helped.

Comment: @numbers: The second method fails when you paste something into the field and then click somewhereelse on the screen. As such it remains in the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use a regex replace for only numbers and return/newline

```
function validate(){
    const input = document.getElementById("input")

    const regex = /[^0-1|\n\r]/g

    input.value = input.value.split(regex).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement should look something along the lines of
if( keycode == 13 || keycode > x1 AND keycode < x2 || keycode > y1 AND keycode < y2)
gives valid input
else
invalid input

Where x is the range of numbers for numbers, and y is the range of numbers for characters.